# Asp.Net Web Api 2 - How to consume JWT access token and user claims using Identity Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, claims, thinktecture-ident-model

I have implemented an authorization server in a Asp.Net Web Api project as explained in this [article](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/).

Now I need to consume the service from a .Net c# client. In the IdentityModel [documentation](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel) I can see below example:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
    "https://server/token",
    "client_id",
    "secret");

var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("scope");
var token = response.AccessToken;
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the purpose of having client Id and a client secret?
2. How a user will be authenticated using user credentials?
3. How can I access the user claims in client side?
4. What is `Scope` and what is the use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `using IdentityModel.Client;` the token can be consumed in following way.

```
 var client = new TokenClient(authenticationUrl);
 client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
 var tokenResponse = await client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(userName, password);
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
 var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
```

in the `token` itself contains claim properties.